# Are any of my mods not cross-compatible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-industrialcraft, minecraft-millenaire

I want to play Minecraft (modded) with my brother but I do not know if they will be Survival Multiplayer (LAN) compatible or if they will be compatible with each other. The mods are:

- Rei's minimap
- Industrial craft
- Optifine
- Balcons Weapons
- Backpacks mod
- Timber mod
- Millenaire
- More arrows mod
- Recipe book
- Death chest
- Flashlight mod

Do any of these mods have known incompatibilities with one another? How would I workaround it if that is the case?

Comment: this is a horribly written question, did you just choose a bunch of random mods and decide you want them or is there some kind of purpose behind this or... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some mods are SMP (Survival Multi-Player) compatible and some are not, most are however. You can find out if a mod is SMP compatible by looking up its website or forum thread.

Some mods work together and some do not, you can find out if a mod works together with other mods by learning how the mod works and lots of trial and error. Most forge mods work together, although sometimes Block IDs need to be changed.